# pywinauto error argument 4: int too long to convert

Tags: python-3.x, automation, pywinauto

I use Python3/pywinauto/and tested app - all are  64. 
I got a error when I trying to expend a tree

**tree_item = systreeview.GetItem([current_menu_item, u'xxxxxx'])**
everything worked with  32 app.

*log:

```
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 1523, in get_item
    texts = [r.text() for r in roots]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 1523, in <listcomp>
    texts = [r.text() for r in roots]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 960, in text
    return self._readitem()[1]
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\common_controls.py", line 1383, in _readitem
    remote_mem)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <class 'OverflowError'>: int too long to convert*
```

Comment: I suggest adding some more detail/context in your question relating to what you are trying to do.

Comment: The details are clear enough to me. Will take a look after the weekend. Maybe it's something app specific, because we auto test it using 64-bit app as well on every Python including 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug. Fixed now. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Are you going to make a pull request on GitHub?

Comment: pywinauto 0.6.3 is out. Another guy confirmed it's fixed there.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed another way in pull request [#373](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/373). pywinauto 0.6.3 is out with the fix.

Just replaced 2 remaining `win32functions.SendMessage` calls with `self.send_message` everywhere.